# How can i get the arglist count?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, argument-list

I am writing a bash script about session management and what I want is if there's something in the arglist not to source the session.

But I couldn't find a way to check the length of `:args`

First of all how do I even assign the output of it into a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`argv()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#argv%28%29) function:

```
$ vim a b c
:echo argv()
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

There is also the `argc()` function to get the length of the argument list (which is the same as `len(argv())`).

---

Note: I found this by going to [`:help function-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#arg-functions) and searching for `arg` :-) I find `:help function-list` to be one of the most useful Vim pages when writing VimScript. Tattoo it on your arm!

It's also documented in some detail at [`:help argument-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#argument-list).

Comment: this is indeed the answer